# Creating LINQ query with DISTINCT, OFFSET and FETCH NEXT

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to implement an SQL query using LINQ (and EF Core 2.2.2), but I am stuck.

The SQL query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT([client].[Id]), [client].[Name]
FROM [Clients] AS [client]
   LEFT JOIN [Documents] as [doc] ON [client].[Id] = [doc].[ClientId]
WHERE client.Name LIKE N'%test%' OR 
      doc.Name LIKE N'%test%' OR 
ORDER BY client.Id DESC
OFFSET 10 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

and I've started writing the query using LINQ:

```
from client in context.Set<Client>()
from doc in client.Documents.DefaultIfEmpty()
where client.Name.Contains("test")
   or doc.Name.Contains("test")
group client by client.Id into c  // this should act as 'distinct'
select c.First()
```

But now I am stuck with how to add `ORDER BY`, `OFFSET` and `FETCH`.

I tried to write something like this:

```
(
    from client in context.Set<Client>()
    from doc in client.Documents.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where client.Name.Contains("test")
       or doc.Name.Contains("test")
    group client by client.Id into c  // this should act as 'distinct'
    select c.First()
)
.OrderByDescending(c => c.Id) // this is still working on IQueryable
.Skip(10)
.Take(10)
.ToListAsync();
```

And it returned the correct results, but when I looked at the SQL profiler, the query didn't include ordering and skipping at all (it was done in the application layer, on the entire set returned by the query).

Is there a way to do this using LINQ, or I need to use plain SQL in my codebase?

Comment: What happens if you write it in method syntax instead of query syntax? By the way, you may find [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) interesting, it is far more efficient than Rowset Pagination

Comment: Which ORM do you use? EF Core?

Comment: Can you use any other ORM? For example, linq2db? It generates exactly the kind of queries you want.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: hi, yes, EF Core, forgot to mention that. Well it's an existing, legacy project, so at this point I believe it would make more sense to write the SQL by hand than to change the ORM.

Comment: Details matter in questions. Like the exact version of EF, because some versions switch to client-side evaluation for grouping, others don't support it. And what is `_clientService.Query()`?

Comment: @GertArnold: sorry, I wasn't aware of that, updated with details. It's EF 2.2 (.NET Core 2.2), and `_clientService.Query()` just returns the dataset from the EF context (I've changed the code to show that instead).

Comment: So you should see a warning that EF switches to client-side evaluation, which explains why the paging doesn't translate. That said, in the SQL query the left join is redundant because you don't select any document columns. You may as well just get Id and Name from Clients without Distinct. And the SQL Distinct is not the same as taking the first document per client as in the LINQ query. You should probably rewrite it into an EXISTS (= Any in LINQ).

Comment: @GertArnold: thanks, well the actual query searches for the string from 5 different joined tables. It was written with `.Any()`/`EXISTS` (and quite straightforward), but the performance was terrible for some reason (with recompile, even with hardcoded parameters, tuning advisor didn't help much). When I switched to plain joins, I got a 5x speed improvement, so now I just wanted to translate it back to LINQ if possible.

Comment: @GertArnold: I am sorry if this is a "XY problem" issue, but I have a feeling Stack Overflow penalizes questions like "why is this slow", while concrete specific questions like these tend to get answered more often. :)

Comment: Yes, performance questions are notoriously hard to answer :) The sorry thing is that a LINQ query works much better with `Any` because you can just stack the predicates and there's no need for `Distinct`. In most cases, analyzing queries with SQL Server's tuning advisor will make it possible to use EXISTS just fine, but yeah, we can't do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct is not possible with query syntax, so just combine them:

```cs
var query = 
    from client in _clientService.Query()
    from doc in client.Documents.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where client.Name.Contains("test") || doc.Name.Contains("test")
    select new { client.Id, client.Name };

var result = await query
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(10)
    .ToListAsync();
```